# How do I find the length of a dataframe in dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

How do I find the length of a dataframe using dask?

For example in pandas, I can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (5, 2)), columns=["A", "B"])
print df['A'].count()
print df
```

Output:

```
5
          A         B
0  1.538531  0.424717
1 -0.929843  1.323648
2 -1.283680  0.056199
3 -0.641035 -1.998241
4 -0.058598 -1.400637
```

In dask I try:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df_dask = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
print df_dask
print df_dask['A'].count()
```

Output:

```
                     A        B
npartitions=2                  
0              float64  float64
2                  ...      ...
4                  ...      ...
Dask Name: from_pandas, 2 tasks

dd.Scalar<series-..., dtype=int32>
```

The real reason I need length is because df_dask.sample() takes a fraction and I want to sample a specified number of entries from the dataframe. I use length to compute this fraction. Is there an easier/faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `len` for length of `dask DataFrame column` or `index`:

```
print (len(df_dask['A']))
5

print (len(df_dask.index))
5
```

Your solution is beter if need count all non `NaN`s values - add `compute`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (5, 2)), columns=["A", "B"])
df.loc[0, 'A'] = np.nan
print (df)
          A         B
0       NaN -1.727669
1 -0.390900  0.573806
2  0.338589 -0.011830
3  2.392365  0.412912
4  0.978736  2.238143

import dask.dataframe as dd
df_dask = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

print (df_dask['A'].count().compute())
4
```

Comment: I tried those but it kind of defeats the purpose of dask doesn't it? Running len() or compute() on a dask dataframe with several million entries takes longer than the equivalent in pandas. I know I can find the number of partitions with df_dask.npartitions (which is very fast) but is there no attribute that stores the total length/ length of each partition?

Comment: @C.L. - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41902069) is what need.

Comment: I went through the link, it seems more suited for large compute clusters. Is it the same if I run it on my laptop? i.e. using dask.distributed and client.persist? Is there really no attribute in the dask dataframe that has the overall length? The real reason I need length is because df_dask.sample()  takes a fraction and I want to sample a specified number of entries from the dataframe. I use length to compute this fraction. Is there an easier/faster way of doing this?

Comment: @C.L.: If you've any type of filtering anywhere, Dask can't know how the final index size until it runs those tasks. And if you're just looking for how many records there are to go about, you actually need to load chunks of records in pandas in order to get the length. If your data is in csv or json format and need a ballpark with data that doesn't contain any newline characters, `wc -l` will be significantly faster.